# Background Image opacity but not text in media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Going through a lot of similar stack questions but seems not solve my case. Like the question says i want to have an opacity for the image but not the next. i have all the text inside another div but its still giving the texts opacity , i am sure its due the parent still having the opacity. In my case i want no opacity on regular screen and on mobile devices have opacity.

i saw an example of giving a background url image which plane white image, but i couldn't replicate it (see below)

background: url(white image) center center repeat;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 


   $('.home-slick-slider').slick({
 
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
   responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
  infinite: true,
     dots: true,
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
});
```

```css
.home-slick-slider>.slick-prev:before {
    background-image: url('../images/chevron-left.png');
    background-size: 50px 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 100px;
 content:"";
}

.home-slick-slider>.slick-next:before {
    background-image: url('../images/chevron-right.png');
    background-size: 50px 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 100px;
 content:"";

}
.home-slick-slider>.slick-prev {
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.home-slick-slider>.slick-next {
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home-slick-text{
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
.home-slick-text h2{
 font-size: 52px;
    line-height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    color: #5d7375;
    text-transform: uppercase;
     zoom: 1;

}

.home-slick-text p{
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
 float: right;
    clear: both;
 width: 40%;
    color: #5d7375;
 zoom: 1;

}

.home-slick-text button{
 float: right;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 20px;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #60bc02;
    border: 1px solid #60bc02;
    color: white;
    width: 10%;
    height: 58px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1079px)
{
      .home-slick-content{opacity: 0.5; }
 .home-slick-text h1{opacity: 4 !important}
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

    <div class="home-slick-slider">
     
        <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          
          <div class="home-slick-content" style="background: url(http://www.baptistphysicianpartners.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/BPP/App_Themes/Default/global/images/a-quality-connection-slide.jpg);width: 100%;height:450px;background-size: 100% 100%;">
                <div class="home-slick-text">
 <h2>A Quality<br>Connection</h2>
            <p>Baptist Physician Partners is a physician-led, clinically integrated network committed to improving the quality of patient care in Northeast Florida.</p>
            <button type="button">Apply Now</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home-slick-content">
        <div class="home-slick-content" style="background: url(http://www.baptistphysicianpartners.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/BPP/App_Themes/Default/global/images/a-quality-connection-slide.jpg);width: 100%;height: 450px;background-size: 100% 100%;">
         
          <div class="home-slick-text">
 <h2>A Quality<br>Connection</h2>
            <p>Baptist Physician Partners is a physician-led, clinically integrated network committed to improving the quality of patient care in Northeast Florida.</p>
            <button type="button">Apply Now</button>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, so you want opacity applied to an image, but not the text associated with that image, is this correct? Also, you only want opacity applied on mobile devices, is this correct?

Comment: Also, part of the reason other answers didn't "solve your case" is because you are asking a multitude of things here. You should take it step by step and research each question individually. Like: How CSS properties of an element affect it's children. And how to apply CSS to mobile only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a background color transparent, but preserve the text opaqueness, you can use an `rgba` colour.

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

If you want to do this with an actual image, you can save the image as a PNG with opacity. This is [supported in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=png).

Otherwise you'll have to [stack two separate elements](https://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/) on top of each other (rather than properly nesting them) in order to avoid the opacity affecting the element with the text.

Comment: i don't have a background color, I have a background image. I want the image to have opacity and text don't.

Comment: As Fenton said, "Otherwise you'll have to stack two separate elements on top of each other (rather than properly nesting them) in order to avoid the opacity affecting the element with the text."

Will work

Answer (score 0):

Your text is a child element of your div with the image, thus applying opacity to the image will also apply it to its children. You can fix this by wrapping all the text elements and buttons that you want to lie above the image in a div, which is no children of the image div, and make this div `position: absolute`, so you can move it above the image. Then you can set the opacity of your image, without changing the opacity of the text.

Answer (score 0):

so i found a way to do this by giving a white image layer. i have re arranged some html as well

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1079px)
{
      .home-slick-content{ 
     background: url(http://www.baptistphysicianpartners.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/BPP/App_Themes/Default/global/images/white-trans-overlay.png);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     height: 450px;

 }
 
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="home-slick-slider">
     
        <div class="home-entire-slide-content"style="background: url(http://www.baptistphysicianpartners.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/BPP/App_Themes/Default/global/images/a-quality-connection-slide.jpg);width: 100%;height:450px;background-size: 100% 100%;">
                
                <div class="home-slick-content">
          
          <div class="home-slick-text" >
 <h2>A Quality<br>Connection</h2>
            <p>Baptist Physician Partners is a physician-led, clinically integrated network committed to improving the quality of patient care in Northeast Florida.</p>
            <button type="button">Apply Now</button>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>

   <div class="home-entire-slide-content"style="background: url(http://www.baptistphysicianpartners.com/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/BPP/App_Themes/Default/global/images/a-quality-connection-slide.jpg);width: 100%;height:450px;background-size: 100% 100%;" >
                
                <div class="home-slick-content">
          
          <div class="home-slick-text" >
 <h2>A Quality<br>Connection</h2>
            <p>Baptist Physician Partners is a physician-led, clinically integrated network committed to improving the quality of patient care in Northeast Florida.</p>
            <button type="button">Apply Now</button>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
```